# Does PostgreSQL support wildcard indexes on JSON?

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, json, eav

I have a multi-tenant service with a table like this:

```
project_id | user_id | user_properties
```

Each project belongs to a different customer and customers can freely attach metadata to their users. A project may have millions of users.

Then a customer may want to find some users inside his project filtering with the `user_properties` (e.g. age grater than X, favorite music equal to Y, etc.)

`user_properties` can be an **arbitrary json of key-value pairs** and a customer can run **arbitrary queries** on the `user_properties`. The json is not nested (only key-value pairs).

Since a query may return many results it would also be useful to use some sort of pagination (e.g. order by user_id + limit). But pagination, together with arbitrary filters, seems an additional issue for performance...

Is it possible to handle that case in PostgreSQL? Is [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) the only solution?

I see that [MongoDB supports wildcard indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-wildcard/): does PostgreSQL offer anything similar?

Comment: In general, you can't create indexes for arbitrary _range_ conditions, only for equality (containment) conditions (e.g. using the `@>` or `?` [operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html)). An EAV model would require a specialized index as well (similar to the one in Laurenz' answer), as your "value" column would not be a `date` and you need to cast it together with a WHERE condition to make sure you are not casting an attribute that contains something else.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work. In particular, you cannot create a single index that will support conditions like

```
WHERE (user_properties ->> 'some random property')::date >= '2000-01-01'::date
```

for arbitrary attributes.

You will have to identify the properties you want to use in comparisons and create specialized indexes on these properties. In the above sample, that would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable (((user_properties ->> 'some random property')::date));
```

It would be better to extract such columns from the JSON and have them be regular table columns.

Comment: Yes, I know that normalization is the best approach in general... but the problem here is that we cannot extract the fields from JSON and have a regular table, because we are dealing with **arbitrary attributes defined by customers of our multi-tenant application**.

Comment: Imagine something like a email service where each customer can add custom columns to his list of contacts... how would you structure that in PostgreSQL? In particular considering that query performance matters (i.e. a search / filter on that contacts, using the custom columns, must be fast)

Comment: I am not telling you if your request is reasonable or not. I am just telling you that you cannot get it. You will have to make concessions, like only allow comparisons with `=`.